# How many textures can I use in a webgl fragment shader?

Tags: webgl

Simple question but I can't find the answer in a specification anywhere. I'm probably missing the obvious answer somewhere.

How many textures can I use at once in a WebGL Fragment shader? If it's variable, what is a reasonable number to assume for PC use? (Not so interested in mobile).

I need at least 23 in one of my shaders so want to know if I'll be able to do that before I start work on the code or if I'll need to do multiple passes.

Comment: I see from an answer that 16 is common but it can vary. Does the standard define any minimum that I can expect to have?

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure you can find out with

```
var maxTexturesInFragmentShader = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS);
```

WebGL (OpenGL ES 2.0) only requires 8 minimum for fragment shaders.

Note that the number of textures you can access is separate from the amount of times you can access 1 texture. Therefore, for example, if you wanted to access 2 textures using only 1 texture unit then combine the textures and adjust your UV coords. So for example put the contents of 2 textures [A] and [B] side by side into one texture [AB] and then

```
vec4 colorFromTexA = texture2D(samplerAB, uvForTexA * vec2(0.5, 1.0));
vec4 colorFromTexB = texture2D(samplerAB, uvForTexB * vec2(0.5, 1.0) + vec2(0.5, 0.0));
```

Of course you probably need to turn set filtering for no mips etc...

Comment: Hmm 8. My application is only for desktop machines, not small phones and things, so I guess I can perhaps rely on more as they all seem to have 16 but I need to at least check the parameter on startup. I guess if I have to do multipass anyway I might be able to make it work with less.

I might be able to combine some of the textures and combine them so that's a good idea, but most of them I need to tile. Still, I might be able to do that in the fragment shader code. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the answer at http://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS

It seems you are out of luck as the stats suggest that most only have 16.

Comment: Right, thank you, that's a useful site. 
Ah well, not so much out of luck as needing the information about which way to go with my code, no point doing multiple passes if I can do it all in one shader, but now I know it's necessary I can get on with it :)